# Merging columns in pandas if none

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have the following table (df):

| ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A11 | None | Q1 |
| B | A21 | Q12 | None |
| A | A31 | S1 | None |
| C | A41 | W12 | None |
| B | A76 | None | O91 |
| A | A90 | A14 | None |
| C | A71 | None | R31 |

The output table should contain another column (ColE) such that, ColA value A is always from ColB, B and C are from ColC, ColD. If the ColC value is none it should take the value from ColD. What I tried so far?

```
if 'A' in df.ColA:
        df['ColE'] = df['ColB']
elif 'B' or 'C' in df.ColA:
        df['ColE']=df['ColC'].fillna(df['ColD'])
```

or

```
df['ColE']=[df['ColB'] if 'A' in df['ColA'] else df['ColC'].fillna(df['ColD'])]
```

But, this doesn't merge all the values. It only works for one if-condition. How do I solve it?

Desired output:

| ColA | ColB | ColC | ColD | ColE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A11 | None | Q1 | A11 |
| B | A21 | Q12 | None | Q12 |
| A | A31 | S1 | None | A31 |
| C | A41 | W12 | None | W12 |
| B | A76 | None | O91 | O91 |
| A | A90 | A14 | None | A90 |
| C | A71 | None | R31 | A71 |

Comment: Can there be other values in `ColA` apart from `A, B, C`?

Comment: No, just A,B,C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a boolean mask by checking the presence of `A` in `ColA`, then use this mask with `np.where`, select the values from `ColB` if the mask holds `True` otherwise select the values from `ColC`/`ColD` giving preference to `ColC`

```
m = df['ColA'].eq('A')
df['ColE'] = np.where(m, df['ColB'], df['ColC'].fillna(df['ColD']))
```

---

```
  ColA ColB  ColC  ColD ColE
0    A  A11  None    Q1  A11
1    B  A21   Q12  None  Q12
2    A  A31    S1  None  A31
3    C  A41   W12  None  W12
4    B  A76  None   O91  O91
5    A  A90   A14  None  A90
6    C  A71  None   R31  R31
```

Comment: Okay, I removed the warning by creating a copy of the original df :)